# Are survey type questions related to implementation allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

I am aware that our main site is a science site.

So, in strict sense, the type of questions I want to ask for may be off-topic.

Our main site has several tags such as `implementation`, `keras`, `pytorch`, `tensorflow` that allows anyone to ask theoretical questions about the implementation packages. Since our main site consider packages and programming languages to a certain extent, I am optimistic enough to ask this question.

And another reason for my optimism is that the great theoretical textbooks of current days deal 95-99% of theory along with 1-5% **suggestions** related to packages.

So, I am wondering whether survey questions on available packages allowed in our main site?

---

Example questions:

What are the list of packages that are generally used by NLP experts?

Are there any functions available to tokenize the text other than `ntlk.regexp.tokenize`?

Answer (score 1):

Those two questions (especially, the second one) are currently off-topic here, as they fall under the general category "software recommendations", which is off-topic here, although there may be some exceptions (e.g. questions related to AGI may not be closed as off-topic, as they may not be on-topic anywhere else and only people that visit our site may know the answer to those questions). You could try asking this type of question on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). We have those tags because some questions may involve those libraries, but I guess we shouldn't have many posts tagged with them. However, a question like "[Why is Python widely used AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3494/2444)" may not be closed as off-topic, as this is more an "implementation"/general question. To be honest, it's not always clear even to me where the boundary is, but, generally, *specific* programming issues are off-topic here. See our [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info and examples.

Note that our site is still subject to change in scope (we're still a public beta site), so we can still discuss changes to our on-topic page, but this type of question has been asked multiple times here and, generally, people seem to agree that programming questions (which should be distinguished from "implementation" questions: again, the boundaries are fuzzy) should be off-topic.